# What is an HTM Word™?

Tags: english, word-property

<sub>*In the spirit of the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463)*</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it an **HTM Word™**.
Use the examples below to find the rule.

$$
% set Title text. (spaces around the text ARE important; do not remove.)
% increase Pad value only if your entries are longer than the title bar.
%
\def\Pad{\P{0.0}}  \def\Title{\textbf{ HTM }}
%
\def\S#1#2{\Space{#1}{20px}{#2px}}\def\P#1{\V{#1em}}\def\V#1{\S{#1}{9}}
\def\T{\Title\textbf{Words}^{\;\!™}\Pad}\def\NT{\Pad\textbf{Not}\T\ }
\smash{\lower{29px}\bbox[teal]{\phantom{\rlap{rubio.2019.05.15}\S{6px}{0}
\begin{array}{cc}\Pad\T&\NT\\\end{array}}}}\atop\def\V#1{\S{#1}{5}}
\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline\Pad\T&\NT\\\hline
%
\text{  navajo}&\text{       apache}\\ \hline
\text{  beefburger}&\text{       vowelburger}\\ \hline
\text{  histogram}&\text{       bar chart}\\ \hline
\text{  triumphal}&\text{       victorious}\\ \hline
\text{  dynamite}&\text{       nitroglycerine}\\ \hline
\text{  Ramanujan}&\text{       Newton}\\ \hline
\text{  hallelujah}&\text{       suzanne}\\ \hline
\text{  regular}&\text{       extraordinary}\\ \hline
\text{  bumpers}&\text{       buffers}\\ \hline
\text{  patchwork}&\text{       agricola}\\ \hline
\text{  television}&\text{       radio}\\ \hline
\text{  interconnected}&\text{       separated}\\ \hline
\hline
\end{array}$$

The CSV version:

```
HTM Words™,Not HTM Words™
navajo,apache
beefburger,vowelburger
histogram,bar chart
triumphal,victorious
dynamite,nitroglycerine
Ramanujan,Newton
hallelujah,suzanne
regular,extraordinary
bumpers,buffers
patchwork,agricola
television,radio
interconnected,separated
```

These are not the only examples of HTM Words™, many more exist.

**What is the special rule these words conform to?**

Hint:

> there are 12 examples.

Comment: This seems like a really challenging puzzle; I and some others have been thinking on it for a week with no success. Would you consider adding a hint?

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- Fun fact: I was going to post the solution this afternoon. But since you have asked, I'll add an hint

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- as usual one "little" hint after makes someone easily find the right answer after a week. Is there any kind of "weaker" hint that I could have written to make the puzzle not-so-obvious?

Comment: I'm not sure (but keep in mind we've been looking at it for some time)!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

An HTM Word is one which:

> Contains a 3-letter month abbreviation *sequentially* among its letters when the word is spelled in reverse.

Like so:

> navajo = **N**av**AJ**o (JAN);
>  beefburger = **B**e**EF**burger (FEB);
>  histogram = histog**RAM** (MAR);
>  triumphal = t**R**ium**P**h**A**l (APR);
>  dynamite = d**Y**n**AM**ite (MAY);
>  Ramanujan = rama**NUJ**an (JUN);
>  hallelujah = halle**LUJ**ah (JUL);
>  regular = re**GU**l**A**r (AUG);
>  bumpers = bum**PE**r**S** (SEP);
>  patchwork = pa**TC**hw**O**rk (OCT);
>  television = tele**V**isi**ON** (NOV);
>  interconnected = inter**C**onnect**ED** (DEC).

As for the name:

> 'HTM' is a 3-letter abbreviation for 'month' (i.e. MTH) in reverse!

Comment: Almost true, except for one little detail: the not-HTM word rot13(frcnengrq) respects your criterion

Comment: @melfnt I don't think it does - that only has it forwards in the first 3 letters doesn't it? EDIT: I have altered the wording of my first spoiler in an attempt to add clarity - I suspect this is purely linguistics... :)

Comment: it "has all the letters" as of your previous wordings. You need to add the order constraint (which you did) otherwise your definition does not work. Well done anyway!